# Is Alsacia meant to be Tanelorn?

Tags: michael-moorcock

In Michael Moorcock's semi-autobiographical fantasy books series, The Sanctuary of the White Friars (starting with *The Whispering Swarm*), Moorcock travels to a place called Alsacia, a pseudo-medieval parallel city populated by characters from adventure literature. It bears many similarities to Tanelorn, being that it seems to exist out of time, and provides respite for its residents.

So my question is: Is it meant to be a version of Tanelorn?